# simplest way to use event emitter in ES6

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js

This is my current implementation of an event emitter.

```
class Table {

  set onDiscard(cb) {
    this._onDiscard = cb;
  }

  notifyDiscard(s) {
    if (this._onDiscard) {
      this._onDiscard(s);
    }
  }
}
```

In the case of having multiple events this gets a burden.

What library/feature/implementation can I use so I can simplify this to a single line.

Comment: The ecmascript6 tag is for questions specifically about ES6 features and behaviors . Don't use it if you are merely using ES6.

Comment: Why not just extend `EventEmitter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make the event type a string?

```
class Table {
  on(eventType, cb) {
    this["_on" + eventType] = cb;
  }
  notify(eventType, s) {
    if(this["_on" + eventType]) {
      this["_on" + eventType](s);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is a solution, I will use this if this is the simplest.

Comment: It's very hard to avoid the temptation to downvote a proposal to roll one's own half-baked event system, specially when the framework the OP says he is using already provides a mature, robust one.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple one that supports multiple handlers:

```
class Table {
    on(type, cb) {
        this['_on' + type] = this['_on' + type] || [];
        this['_on' + type].push(cb);
    }

    emit(type, args) {
        this['_on' + type] && this['_on' + type].forEach((cb) => { cb(args) });
    }
}

var table = new Table();

table.on('started', function() { alert('started'); });
table.emit('started');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean ES6 specifically or just ECMAScript? Since ES6 is backwards compatible you could use any event library in ES5 (javascript) out there.

I'd suggest [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org), as what you're doing seems to be model/view logic, which Backbone is actually very good at. It is very minimalistic, has it's own event emitter / listener (see Events section) implementation which is very similar to the one used by the DOM internally, and it helps separating your view and model logic very well.

I have implemented a simple app recently as a proof of concept using Backbone with ES6 and it's compatible just the way you'd expect. Extending the base classes using ES6's `extend` does just what underscore's `extend` does when calling `extend` as suggested in Backbone's docs.

I used [babeljs](http://babeljs.io) for transpilation in that case.

Comment: I am already using emberjs, so backbone would be overkill, I need a simpler solution, or a library with this specific solution.

Comment: In that case, could you extend Ember's variant of that? http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html

Comment: If I use this, I can't use `class` keyword I think, could you provide an example if it's possible.

Comment: Just replace any A = Foo.extends({ ... }) you see in the docs with A extends Foo { }. I assume Ember's internals are similar to Backbone's, so that should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ember, it has perfectly good mechanisms for emitters and notifiers. There's no reason not to use them. There's also no reason to use another, different class mechanism, just because it happens to exist in ES6, when Ember already provides one. Nor should you try to somehow awkwardly marry the Ember world with the ES6 class world.

Remember that ES6 classes (which some people say should not have been in the spec in the first place) are merely light syntactic sugar over JS prototype-based classes. So you should ask yourself the question: if I was already using Ember, would I implement my own emitter/notifier system using prototype-based classes? I doubt it. There's no reason to have two parallel class paradigms. Dance with the one you brought.

Comment: why don't ember switch to sweet sugars instead. I will stick to SpiderPig's solution.

Comment: If you don't want to use Ember, then don't use it. If you want to use it, then use it. Ember's class mechanism, love it or hate it, provides far more functionality that plain vanilla classes whether overlaid with ES6 sugar or not. It's not a welcoming environment for those who want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: So can I just replace `A = Foo.extends({` with `A extends Foo`?